# Вывод непонятной ошибки _img_

Tags: qt, qt5, qtcreator

Выводит вот такую ошибку QuaZIP
     ошибка: `undefined reference to _imp___ZN10JlCompress12extractFilesE7QString11QStringListS0_`

Сама строка с кодом

```
QStringList list = JlCompress::extractFiles(ZipFile, Files, Directory);
```

Прикрепил вот так, если что не правильно - исправьте. Заранее спасибо, с меня +

```
    #-------------------------------------------------
    #
    # Project created by QtCreator 2020-04-05T15:11:14
    #
    #-------------------------------------------------

    QT       += core gui network



    greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

    TARGET = GTLauncher
    TEMPLATE = app

    # The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
    # any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
    # depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
    # deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
    DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

    # You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
    # In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
    # You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
    #DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

    CONFIG += c++11

    SOURCES += \
            main.cpp \
            mainwindow.cpp

    HEADERS += \
            mainwindow.h

    FORMS += \
            mainwindow.ui

    win32:RC_ICONS += favicontop.ico

    # Default rules for deployment.
    qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
    else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
    !isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

    RESOURCES += \
        resource.qrc

    INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_32\include\QtZlib"
    LIBS += -L"C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_32\bin"

    win32 {
        headers.path=$$PREFIX/include/quazip
        headers.files=$$HEADERS
        target.path=$$PREFIX/lib
        INSTALLS += headers target
        # workaround for qdatetime.h macro bug
        DEFINES += NOMINMAX
    }

        CONFIG += staticlib
        CONFIG += debug_and_release
```

Comment: Вы неверно прикрепили либу. Покажите pro-файл

Comment: В LIBS прикрепляют сами либы, а не пути к ним `LIBS += -L"C:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\mingw73_32\bin"` - эта строка бессмысленна

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему

Чтобы ее решить, нужно добавить в .pro файл проекта

```
DEFINES += QUAZIP_STATIC
```